# Find the product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of degree $n$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, commutative-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Let $H_n$ be the product of all monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[T]$ whose degree is **equal** to $n$. What is known about $H_n$? Is there an explicit formula? Where does it appear in the literature?

It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106721) that the product of all monic irreducible polynomials whose degree **divides** $n$ is equal to $T^{\large p^n}-T$. It follows that, if $\ell$ is a prime number, then
$$H_{\ell} = (T^{\large  p^\ell} - T)/(T^p - T).$$
More generally, if $n = \ell^s$ is a power of a prime number, then
$$H_{\large \ell^s} = (T^{\large p^{\ell^s}} - T)/(T^{\large p^{\ell^{s-1}}} - T).$$
For the product of two primes it is also easy, but for $n = 12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$ we need the principle of inclusion-exclusion to find (if I am not mistaken)
$$H_{12} = \dfrac{(T^{\large p^{12}} - T) (T^{\large p^2}-T)}{(T^{\large p^4}-T)(T^{\large p^6}-T)}.$$
I assume that a similar approach works in general. I am looking in particular for a good reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have the formula, valid for all $n$:
$$T^{p^n}-T=\prod_{d\mid n}H_d(T).$$
[The general (multiplicative) version of Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Multiplicative_notation) then gives the answer
$$H_n(T)=\prod_{d\mid n}(T^{p^d}-T)^{\mu(n/d)}.$$

---

This formula is also the content of Theorem 3.29 in [Lidl & Niederreiter](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/finite-fields/75BDAA74ABAE713196E718392B9E5E72). The variant formulation in Qiaochu Yuan's answer is Theorem 3.31 (loc.cit.).

Answer (score 3):

We can write down something with no divisions as follows. $T^{p^n} - T$ has the factorization (over $\mathbb{Z}$!)

$$T^{p^n} - T = T \prod_{d \mid p^n - 1} \Phi_d(T)$$

where $\Phi_d$ are the [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). The roots of $\Phi_d(T)$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ are the primitive $d^{th}$ roots of unity; on the other hand, if $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ then the condition that its minimal polynomial have degree exactly $n$ is the condition that $\alpha$ has order exactly $n$ under the Frobenius map, meaning $n$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $\alpha^{p^k} = \alpha$, or equivalently, if $\Phi_d(\alpha) = 0$, that $n$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $p^k \equiv 1 \bmod d$. This gives

$$\boxed{ H_n(T) = \prod_{\text{ord}_d(p) = n} \Phi_d(T) }.$$